# In an abstract class constructor, why I do need to call a constructor of a virtual base that will never to called?

Tags: c++, class, virtual, multiple-inheritance, language-lawyer

I face the well known "dreaded" diamond situation :

```
  A
 / \
B1 B2
 \ /
  C
  |
  D
```

The class `A` has, say the constructor `A::A(int i)`. I also want to forbid a default instantiation of a `A` so I declare the default constructor of `A` as `private`.

The classes `B1` and `B2` are virtually derived from `A` and have some constructors and a `protected` default constructor.

[edit]
The constructors of `B1` and `B2` don't call the default constructor of `A`.
[reedit]
The default constructors of `B1` and `B2` don't call the default constructor of `A` either.
[reedit]
[edit]

The class `C` is an abstract class and has some constructors that don't call any of the `A`, `B1` or `B2` constructors.

In the class `D`, I call the constructor `A::A(i)` and some constructor of `C`.

So as expected, when `D` is created, it first creates a `A` to solve the dreaded diamond problem, then it creates `B1`, `B2` and `C`. Therefore there is no call of the default constructor of `A` in `B1`, `B2` and `C` because if there was, it would create many instances of `A`.

The compiler rejects the code because the default constructor of `A` is `private`. If I set it to `protected` it compiles.

What I don't understand is that when I run the code, the default constructor of `A` is never called (as it should be). So why doesn't the compiler allow me to set it as `private`?

[edit]
okay I'll write an example... but it hurts ;-)

```
class A{
        public:
                A(int i):i_(i){};
                virtual ~A(){};
        protected:
                int i_;
        private:
                A():i_(0){};/*if private => compilation error, if protected => ok*/
};

class B1: public virtual A{
        public:
                B1(int i):A(i){};
                virtual ~B1(){};
        protected:
                B1():A(0){};
};

class B2: public virtual A{
        public:
                B2(int i):A(i){};
                virtual ~B2(){};
        protected:
                B2():A(0){};
};

class C: public B1, public B2{
        public:
                C(int j):j_(j){};
                virtual ~C()=0;
        protected:
                int j_;

};

C::~C(){};

class D: public C{
        public:
                D(int i,int j):A(i),C(j){};
                ~D(){};
};

int main(){
        D d(1,2);
}
```

The compiler says that in constructor of `C`, `A::A()` is private. I agree with this, but as `C` is an abstract class, it can't be instantiated as a complete object (but it can be instantiated as a base class subobject, by instantiating a `D`).
[edit]

I added the tag `language-lawer' on someone's recommendation.

Comment: not sure if I understand but the default constructor might be needed by B1 and B2

Comment: enough text, plz show some code.

Comment: @PinkFloyd then that's your answer: it is needed to create the derived objects

Comment: @RakibulHasan, well I'm not sure that it would help... but if it's really not clear like this, i can update my question

Comment: @PinkFloyd Any reason not to show code? Does it hurt to give an SsCCE?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, yet I downvoted because you only give text but no code and no exact compiler error message.

Comment: @MarcoA. I think you're right...

Comment: Looks quite interesting. I'ld read 12.6.2 8 "[ Note: An abstract class (10.4) is never a most derived class, thus its constructors never initialize virtual
base classes, therefore the corresponding mem-initializers may be omitted. —end note ]" like you are right. Yet the code does not compile on gcc 4.8.2 and not on MSVC 2013. BTW, you might consider adding the tag language-lawyer.

Comment: "_C is a pure virtual class_" no, an **abstract** class

Comment: @curiousguy : you're right... when I wrote the question I was still confused ;-) But unfortunatly it doesn't the meaning of my question...

Comment: @PinkFloyd I changed the wording of parts of your question. I think your question got downvoted for formal issues. Other then that, it is a good question.

Comment: @curiousguy, thanks for the update

Comment: Which compiler? The code compiles with gcc 9.2, clang 9.0.0, icc 19.0.1 and msvc 19.24 (testet on godbolt). So it looks like the current compilers share your understanding and a compiler update would help.

Comment: @WernerHenze it was in 2014... so I probably had an older compiler at the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't have an access control specifier for member functions that can only be called from a derived class, but a constructor for an abstract class can only be called from a derived class by definition of an abstract class.

The compiler cannot know in advance exactly which classes are instantiated (this is a runtime property), and it cannot know which constructors are potentially called before link-time.

The standard text (emphasis mine):

> All sub-objects representing virtual base classes are initialized by
>   the constructor of the most derived class (1.8 [intro.object]). If the
>   constructor of the most derived class does not specify a
>   mem-initializer for a virtual base class V, then V's default
>   constructor is called to initialize the virtual base class subobject.
>   If V does not have an accessible default constructor, the
>   initialization is ill-formed. A mem-initializer naming a virtual base
>   class shall be **ignored during execution** of the constructor of any
>   class that is not the most derived class.

1) **It makes no exception for abstract classes** and can only be interpreted as saying that all constructors should do a (sometimes fake) attempt at calling virtual base constructors.

2) It says that at **runtime** such attempts are ignored.

Some committee members have stated a different opinion in [DR 257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#257):

> 257. Abstract base constructors and virtual base initialization
>
> Section: 12.6.2  [class.base.init]     Status: CD2     Submitter: Mike
>   Miller     Date: 1 Nov 2000 [Voted into WP at October, 2009 meeting.]
>
> Must a constructor for an abstract base class provide a
>   mem-initializer for each virtual base class from which it is directly
>   or indirectly derived? Since the initialization of virtual base
>   classes is performed by the most-derived class, and since an abstract
>   base class can never be the most-derived class, there would seem to be
>   no reason to require constructors for abstract base classes to
>   initialize virtual base classes.
>
> It is not clear from the Standard whether there actually is such a
>   requirement or not. The relevant text is found in 12.6.2
>   [class.base.init] paragraph 6:

(...quoted above)

> This paragraph requires only that the most-derived class's constructor
>   have a mem-initializer for virtual base classes. Should the silence be
>   construed as permission for constructors of classes that are not the
>   most-derived to omit such mem-initializers?

There is no "silence". The general rule applies as *there is no specific rule for abstract classes*.

> Christopher Lester, on comp.std.c++, March 19, 2004: If any of you
>   reading this posting happen to be members of the above working group,
>   I would like to encourage you to review the suggestion contained
>   therein, as it seems to me that the final tenor of the submission is
>   both (a) correct (the silence of the standard DOES mandate the
>   omission) and (b) describes what most users would intuitively expect
>   and desire from the C++ language as well.
>
> The suggestion is to make it clearer that constructors for abstract
>   base classes should not be required to provide initialisers for any
>   virtual base classes they contain (as only the most-derived class has
>   the job of initialising virtual base classes, and an abstract base
>   class cannot possibly be a most-derived class).

The suggestion cannot make "clearer" something that doesn't exist now.

Some committee members are taken their desire for reality and it is very wrong.

(snip example and discussion similar to OP's code)

> **Proposed resolution (July, 2009):**
>
> Add the indicated text (moved from paragraph 11) to the end of 12.6.2
>   [class.base.init] paragraph 7:
>
> ...The initialization of each base and member constitutes a
>   full-expression. Any expression in a mem-initializer is evaluated as
>   part of the full-expression that performs the initialization. A
>   mem-initializer where the mem-initializer-id names a virtual base
>   class is ignored during execution of a constructor of any class that
>   is not the most derived class.
>
> Change 12.6.2 [class.base.init]
>   paragraph 8 as follows:
>
> If a given non-static data member or base class is not named by a
>   mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no
>   mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer)
>   and **the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class** (10.4
>   [class.abstract]), then
>
> if the entity is a non-static data member that has a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer, the entity is initialized as specified in
>   8.5 [dcl.init];
>
> otherwise, if the entity is a variant member (9.5 [class.union]), no
>   initialization is performed;
>
> otherwise, the entity is default-initialized (8.5 [dcl.init]).
>
> [Note: An abstract class (10.4 [class.abstract]) is never a most
>   derived class, thus its constructors never initialize virtual base
>   classes, therefore the corresponding mem-initializers may be omitted.
>   —end note] After the call to a constructor for class X has
>   completed...
>
> Change 12.6.2 [class.base.init] paragraph 10 as follows:
>
> Initialization shall proceed proceeds in the following order:
>
> First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class as
>   described below (1.8 [intro.object]), virtual base classes shall be
>   are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first
>   left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes,
>   where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base class
>   names in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> Then, direct base classes shall be are initialized in declaration
>   order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the
>   order of the mem-initializers).
>
> Then, non-static data members shall be are initialized in the order
>   they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the
>   order of the mem-initializers).
>
> Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
>
> [Note: the declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and
>   member subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of
>   initialization. —end note]
>
> Remove all normative text in 12.6.2 [class.base.init] paragraph 11,
>   keeping the example:
>
> All subobjects representing virtual base classes are initialized by
>   the constructor of the most derived class (1.8 [intro.object]). If the
>   constructor of the most derived class does not specify a
>   mem-initializer for a virtual base class V, then V's default
>   constructor is called to initialize the virtual base class subobject.
>   If V does not have an accessible default constructor, the
>   initialization is ill-formed. A mem-initializer naming a virtual base
>   class shall be ignored during execution of the constructor of any
>   class that is not the most derived class. [Example:...

The DR is marked "CD2": the committee agrees this was an issue and the language definition is changed to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your effort ! I'm not sure I understood everything in your answer but I least I understood that there's an issue somewhere and thats not my fault...

Comment: It's not clear why you would quote C++03 here as if it were the most recent version, but it wasn't ever "very wrong": "First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class" was already present, so there was no place in the order of initialization that the "the entity is default-initialized" phrasing was meant to be _used_ for such a *mem-initializer*.  It's also obviously wrong to read "If a given non-static data member or base class is not named" as including (all) virtual base classes, since it would then have to include all indirect base classes as well.

Comment: @DavisHerring 1) C++ inheritance is an extremely stable (and mostly sane) part of an extremely instable (and sometimes insane) C++ language semantics, so which std version is quoted about inheritance shouldn't matter that much. 2) I don't understand how do you interpret that std clause. What should compilers do?

Comment: It’s so stable that in 2009 it was being revised (fixing what you say was an error); you could have just cited C++11 and said it was an out-of-date compiler.  My argument is that even before CWG257 there wasn’t a coherent reading of the standard that synthesized a useless, ill-formed *mem-initializer* for a virtual base of an abstract class, although the wording was poor in that it did not clearly address static _vs._ dynamic concerns (such that the same argument could be made for a non-abstract intermediate base that was simply never used as a most-derived class).

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm afraid you completely misread what I wrote. I wrote that the std text was never ambiguous or defective and that having a complete ctor-init-list in each and every class was a requirement, and that saying the std was in error is very wrong. "_there wasn’t a coherent reading of the standard that synthesized a useless, ill-formed mem-initializer for a virtual base of an abstract class_" The coherent reading was: you have to write your ctor-init-list completely even though they will never be used.

Comment: "_such that the same argument could be made for a non-abstract intermediate base that was simply never used as a most-derived class_" Exactly, and how would you ever fix that? Or will you make the nuance of the two constructors: "complete object constructor" and "base object constructor" as in the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html)?

Comment: @curiousguy: I’m not saying the standard didn’t need improving—this amount of interpretive effort should never be required.  In the case of a non-abstract class, it’s obvious that separate translation requires generating a complete-object constructor, so it was only reasonable to infer the requirement that it be well-formed; under the interpretation that _that_ was the “creative reading” of the standard, there was no reason to extend that interpretation to abstract classes where it would have no effect except to render certain programs ill-formed.