# c++ can classes used as virtual bases have constructors with parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-inheritance

I am C++ newbie and i was trying to build a multiple inheritance class, with a common virtual inherited class( see code below). What my book politely ignored was the  case where the virtual inherited class' constructor has parameters. The code below is my attempt to do that.
If i remove the virtual inheritance of the class base in both derived class the code builds ok. However if i keep the way it is it won't build.( g++ under ubuntu)

I have several questions:

1) Least important first: why the code is not building?

2) Can virtual inherited classes have constructors with parameters?

3) If question 2) is true, then how the following line it is evaluated?

```
derived(int i,int j, int k):derived1(i,j),derived2(j,k){};
```

each derived class calls base constructor,each with second parameter. But only one copy of the base exist in derived since it is inherited as virtual. I want to understand in this case which base constructors is executed and with what parameter: j or k? ( i am not sure that this line is valid).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
int x;
public:
base(int i){cout<<"Constructing base "<<i<<endl;x=i;}
~base(){cout<<"Destructing base"<<endl;}
};

class derived1:virtual public base
{
int x1;
public:
derived1(int i,int j): base(j){cout<<"Constructing derived1 "  <<i<<endl;x1=i;}
~derived1(){cout<<"Destructing derived1"<<endl;}
};

class derived2:virtual public base
{
int x2;
public:
derived2(int i,int j): base(j){cout<<"Constructing derived2 "<<i<<endl;x2=i;}
~derived2(){cout<<"Destructing derived2"<<endl;}
};

class derived:public derived1, public derived2
{
int z;
public:
derived(int i,int j, int k):derived1(i,j),derived2(j,k){cout<<"Constructing derived "<<k<<endl;z=k;}
~derived(){cout<<"Destructing derived"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
derived ob(2,3,4);
}
```

Comment: did you  forget to put the code?

Comment: yes. i did miss it and i am looking for ways to edit it.

Comment: There's an [edit] link (gray text) just below the question.

Comment: [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html) is a tutorial explaining the issue.

Comment: Virtual bases are usually interface classes and these classes have very simple construction. Do you really need a constructor with parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual base classes are initialized by the constructor of the *most derived class*, even if the most derived class does not inherit from them directly.

This means that if your class hierarchy includes any virtual base classes that require constructor parameters, the most derived class constructor has to name them in its *mem-initializer-list* and supply any required parameters at that point. Since virtual base classes are initialized before any non-virtual base classes, it's recommended to place them before non-virtual base classes in the initializer list:

```
derived(int i, int j, int k)
    : base(i)     // note: derived does not inherit directly from base
    , derived1(i, j)
    , derived2(j, k)
{
    cout << "Constructing derived " << k << endl;
    z = k;
}
```

This also means that if a derived class depends on particular parameters being passed to a virtual base, it should be marked `final` so that it cannot be inherited from; otherwise, any inheriting class could pass the "wrong" parameters.

Note also that `derived1` and `derived2` have to supply constructor parameters for `base`, even though they will never be used. This is a bit of a bug in the language, but no-one has bothered enough to clean it up yet ([DR257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#257) via https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214536/567292)

Comment: yes  your are right. i have updated derived constructor the way you described it. and now the code builds. also by declaring derived ob(2,3,4); the output of the program became:Constructing base 2
Constructing derived1 2
Constructing derived2 3
Constructing derived 4
Destructing derived
Destructing derived2
Destructing derived1
Destructing base
which means that the i=2 was sent to base constructor. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Any class in a hierarchy can list its virtual base classes among its mem-initializer-list (the part of the constructor definition after `:`), but only one of them will actually execute these constructors: the most derived class.

Let's imagine a setup like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct V
{
  explicit V(char c) { std::cout << c << '\n'; }
};

struct A : virtual V
{
  A() : V('a') {}
};

struct B : A, virtual V
{
  B() : V('b') {}
};

struct C : B
{
  C() : V('c') {}
};

int main()
{
  A a; // prints 'a'
  B b; // prints 'b'
  C c; // prints 'c'
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f70674abdbbc53ac)

As you can see, even though all of `A`, `B`, and `C` initialise `V` in their constructor, only the most derived class (the type of the object you're actually creating) executes its initialiser.

Now let's imagine we add a class `D` like this:

```
struct D : C
{
  D() {}
};
```

This will [not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/369c7451b5056832)—`D` does not list `V` among its mem-initializer-list, so the default constructor is to be used, but that doesn't exist.

---

To address your concrete example with `derived` derived from both `derived1` and `derived2`: when creating an object of type `derived`, `derived` is the most derived type therefore only the constructor of `derived` itself can pass arguments to the `base` constructor. Any initialisation of `base` inside the constructors of `derived1` and `derived2` will simply be ignored when creating a `derived` object.

Comment: thanks for answer. i understand your point. My question, as now made clear by the code is how to the to choice is done , between the same level of derivation(e.g derived1, derived2) More specific, if this line is valid, which of the constructors will pass the arguments to     base:derived(int i,int j, int k):derived1(i,j),derived2(j,k){cout<<"Constructing derived "<<k<<endl;z=k;}

Comment: @exilat none of them only `derived` can call the constructor `base`

Comment: @exilat I've edited the answer to address that; tobi303 is right.

Comment: @Angew,@tobi303 you are right both. i must add the base constructor in the derived constructor,even that looks a bit weird to me. Thanks a lot!